# Calculating length with different units

Tags: java, object-oriented

We have an exercise to design a simple library, which can calculate some length with different unit, e.g.

```
2m*2 + 20cm/2 - 5mm
```

and the result can be any of:

```
4.095m
409.5cm
4095mm
```

I want to design it in Object-oriented, and have a solution like this:

```
public class Length {

    private final double value;
    private final Unit unit;

    public Length(double value, Unit unit) {
        this.value = value;
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Length length = (Length) obj;
        return this.unit.toMM(this.value) == length.unit.toMM(length.value);
    }

    public Length add(Length added) {
        return new Length(this.unit.toMM(this.value) + added.unit.toMM(added.value), Unit.mm);
    }

    public Length subtract(Length another) {
        return new Length(this.unit.toMM(this.value) - another.unit.toMM(another.value), Unit.mm);
    }

}

enum Unit {
    m(1000), cm(10), mm(1);
    private final int rate;

    Unit(int rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public double toMM(double value) {
        return rate * value;
    }
}
```

It works, but I have several questions:

1. Is there anything wrong from the OO point of view?
2. `Unit` has a method `toMM` which is bind to a concrete type of unit `mm`(millimeter), I don't feel good about it, is there any way to improve it? Or it's just acceptable since we have to choose one?
3. `Length` has chosen `mm` for all kinds of unit, is it good? I'm looking for a way to avoid it, but not found

These questions are mostly based on this possible requirement change: don't want to support `mm` anymore. Most of the code has to be modified in this case.

---

Update: [from this article](https://www.clear.rice.edu/comp212/99-fall/handouts/week1/person/), seems it's not a good idea to use `enum` here for different units?

Comment: There should be a bug when comparing two `double` here with `==`, but now let's ignore it

Comment: Your example at the start is a little confusing. 2 meters squared + 20 cm squared - 5 mm.  Not sure what you would expect this to be other than an error?

Comment: @Paddy maybe that's meant to be read as "2 meters times 2, i.e. 4 meters" plus "20 centimeters divided by 2, i.e. 10 centimeters" minus 5 millimeters?

Answer (score 6):

An alternative approach would be to say that a length is measured in SI units (meters).

Also, if performance is not a concern, using a `BigDecimal` instead of a `double` would avoid potential rounding errors.

It could look like:

```
public class Length {
  private final BigDecimal meters;
  public Length(BigDecimal meters) { ... }
  public Length(BigDecimal value, Unit unit) { /*convert to m*/}

  public BigDecimal getLength(Unit unit) { /*convert to unit*/ }
  public BigDecimal getLength() { /*return length in SI, i.e. meters*/ }

  public int hashCode() { return meters.hashCode(); }
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    /*usual checks */
    return meters.compareTo(other.meters) == 0;
  }
  //other methods
}
```

This also avoids having to arbitrarily choose a "base" unit (mm in your example).

Finally I would suggest defining an interface for Unit:

```
public interface Unit {
  BigDecimal toMeters(BigDecimal length);
  //and possibly additional helper methods:
  default BigDecimal convert(BigDecimal length, Unit sourceUnit) { ... }
}
```

Then your enum would be:

```
public enum StandardUnit implements Unit {
  MM("0.001"); //etc.

  private final BigDecimal multiplier;
  StandardUnit(String mulltiplier) { this.multiplier = new BigDecimal(multiplier); }
  public BigDecimal toMeters(BigDecimal length) { return length.multiply(multiplier); }
}
```

This will allow a more flexible design where you can add units by implementing the interface or use the provided standard units.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you must implement `hashcode` if you implement `equals`. Read up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027777/relationship-between-hashcode-and-equals-method-in-java).

I don't think that `equals` should convert to mm. I think it should compare units `&&` value. It's equals, not equivalent, if you want to have that behaviour, give it another name (suggestion `isSameLength`). Or you could convert to mm in the constructor and only store mm internally, and maybe the `toString` applies intelligence about how best to display it and possibly with an overload that takes the desired display unit.

You say to ignore the `double` comparison, but just a quick note on that, you could use a decimal type such as `BigDecimal` internally, because its how it is actually being represented to the user and the maths won't leave you with any rounding errors that later make comparison hard.

Another approach could be to drop the enum and have classes for each type and a base type `Length`.

e.g: You could have types for each Unit of measure, and return a MM instance from your `toMM`. Then move `toMM` to each subtype, this suggestion will actually remove need for your `enum`:

(constructors omitted, but they take just one BigDecimal)

```
public abstract class Length {
    public abstract Millimeter toMM();

    public boolean isSameLength(Length other){
        return toMM().equals(other.toMM()); //Must implement equals on Millimeter class
    }
}

public class Meter extends Length {
    private final BigDecimal meters;

    @Override
    public Millimeter toMM() {
        return new Millimeter(meters * 1000);
    }
}

public class Centimeter extends Length {
    private final BigDecimal centimeters;

    @Override
    public Millimeter toMM() {
        return new Millimeter(centimeters * 100);
    }
}

public class Millimeter extends Length {
    private final BigDecimal millimeters;

    @Override
    public Millimeter toMM() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

The nice thing about this is it can be extended without modifying existing code. If I want to start using Furlongs:

```
public class Furlong extends Length {
    private final BigDecimal furlongs;

    @Override
    public Millimeter toMM() {
        return new Millimeter(furlongs * 201168);
    }
}
```

And I do not have to modify an enum or any other file.

Comment: Thanks, @weston. A similar question: abstract base class `Length` now have a dependency of `Millimeter` in your design now. So it still will be a big change if "don't want to support millimeter anymore" happens

Comment: Another question is about this `It's equals, not equivalent`. What's the difference between them, and why it's better to use another method for my `equals`?

Comment: All lengths need to be converted to a common format for comparison. You can pick a different common length unit for that if you don't want Millimeter to exist.

Comment: 1km is equivalent to 1000m because their lengths are equal. But they themselves are not equal, because one has a display unit of km and the other m.

Comment: Maybe another example. 4 quarters add up to $1, they are equivalent, but they are not equal. To a coin collector, even those quarters are not equal to each other if they have different years on them.

Comment: If you are recording year of the coin, then you'd better include it in any equality comparison. Just like if you are recording unit of measure you better include it.

Comment: If unit of measure is lost in a constructor because internally everything is being stored as one common unit then you can't and don't need to include it. So generally equality would compare every field.

Comment: `decimal` appears to not exist, I'm getting mixed up with c# again

Comment: "So it still will be a big change if "don't want to support millimeter anymore" I don' think will be big change, most code should be talking in terms of `Length` and there just be a few explicit references to Millimeter.

Comment: I entirely disagree with the argument re: equals().  The class name is Length.   In all ways 1000 mm is equal to 1m and is equal to 3.28084 ft.   A length is simply a distance, and the distances are equal.  The coin argument is equally disingenuous.   A dollar is a dollar no matter how you add it up.  BUT, this only applies to the concept of MONEY.   If you want a coin collector's app,  then you're not talking about Money at all.  You're talking about discrete objects, with a value different than the face value.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore the point is that the system designer decides which properties should be compared, you cannot decide ahead of time that all coins must be compared on their face $ value or that all lengths must be compared by the physical length the represent. I'd say it is generally a smell to ignore properties during equality comparison.

Comment: No, that's not correct at all.  The CLIENT defines equality.  If the client is an engineer, or a carpenter, then the only thing they care about is that 1 m = 1000 mm.   In fact, I doubt there is anyone in the world who would want a program/class/framework that states that 1 m !=1000mm .  It is factually incorrect.  Just because the coding decision  checks off something on your smell list, doesn't mean it's bad.  Limburger stinks, and delivers exactly as expected.  A smell is a warning, not an error.

Comment: Notwithstanding the discussion, above, the way I would handle the problem would probably use Measurements(number, Unit) , with units done similarly to what you did above, and Length, with all it's operations would be a class measured in a single unit.  OP chose mm. Depending on the usage, we could go with nanos, Planck Lengths, Wavelength of a particular colour of light, etc.  Now, we'd both be correct.  Lengths are equal if their magnitudes are equal, and measurements are equal if all their properties are equal.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Well I'm not saying 1m != 1000mm, because object equality is not mathematical equality. Ask yourself this, if I have a property I will ignore during comparison (i.e. unit of measure), then it's clearly not that important, so why would I store it on the object? So one suggestion I made was to convert everything to a single UOM internally and use that unit of measure to prime that field only.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore The other suggestion was to be explicit about the type of comparison, e.g. `isLengthSame` because it's pointless to overload `equals` and give yourself a dodgy equality contract when you can define explicit methods.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Re equality contract I refer you to *Effective Java item 8 Obey the equality contract "4. For each “significant” field in the class, check if that field of the argument
matches the corresponding field of this object."*. Our discussion boils down to whether unit of measure is a significant field or not. I don't have enough information on this, but I think it safer to not override equals as Joshua Bloch says at the start of item 8 **The easiest way to avoid problems is not to
override the equals method** which is my preferred approach of using an explicit `isLengthSame` method.

Comment: But the overriding principle is the Principle of Least Surprise/Astonishment.  I would be astonished if 1 m != 1000mm.  And as a user of the class called length, the least surprising thing would be that two lengths that are equal, would be programmatically equal.  Don't be beholden to guidelines, they are not rules.   Certainly the EASIEST way is not to override it.  But easiest isn't always best.  But yes, you should always ask the question "Do I need to?".  But the utility of equals over some other non-overridden method is something I want.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore if you have to convert values during your check for equals, they're not really equal/the class isn't storing the essence of what it represents. Conversion so easily leads to a breaking equals contract and it can be avoided so easily it's hard to imagine why one would go down this route.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore ps, you understand I approve assylias answer, and that allows new Length(1000, mm).equals(new Length(1, m)) because it rightfully discards the uom and does the common conversion up front. I'm not against every equals, I suggested that solution too. But if uom is a field, that's where I think it's a bit dodgy because why is it a field? If it has some other use is it right to ignore it in the equals. That we do not have enough info on.

Answer (score 1):

With minimal changes of the original code:

```
public class Length {
    private final double value;
    private final Unit unit;

    public Length(double value, Unit unit) {
        this.value = value;
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Length length = (Length) obj;
        return this.unit.normalize(this.value) == length.unit.normalize(length.value);
    }

    public Length add(Length added) {
        return new Length(this.unit.normalize(this.value) + added.unit.normalize(added.value), Unit.base);
    }

    public Length subtract(Length another) {
        return new Length(this.unit.normalize(this.value) - another.unit.normalize(another.value), Unit.base);
    }

}

enum Unit {
    m(1000), cm(10), mm(1);
    private final int rate;

    Unit(int rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public double normalize(double value) {
        return rate * value;
    }

    static Unit base = mm;
}
```

If `mm` is no longer supported, only `Unit.base` must be modified.

Comment: I don't like "rate".  It's a number, that when multiplied by this unit, gives the equal measurement in a base unit (in this case mm).    CONVERT_TO_BASE_UNIT_MULTIPLIER is explicit, and good, but a bit wordy.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
public Length add(Length added) {
    return new Length(this.unit.toMM(this.value)
                        + added.unit.toMM(added.value), Unit.mm);
}

public Length subtract(Length another) {
    return new Length(this.unit.toMM(this.value)
                        - another.unit.toMM(another.value), Unit.mm);
}
```

From an API perspective, you may want to consider if it's suitable to 'default' `Unit` as `Unit.mm` for all the results of these operations. In other words, when the user is adding 2 meters to 2 meters, is the result better represented as 4 meters, or 4000 millimeters? How about adding 50 centimeters to 2 meters? Should it default to 2.5 meters, or 250 centimeters?

What's nice about your code is that your classes are properly modeled as immutable ones - to nitpick, `Length` should be made `final` too if you do not wish to extend it. Just remember that the comparison in `equals(Object)` must check for the same type as well, i.e. catch these as `false` assertions instead of having the JVM throw a `ClassCastException`.